# Search query involving two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, users and sales. `sales.userId = user.id`
I am trying to use following query. To search parameters in both users and sales.

```
SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId WHERE 'users.fullname' like '%Cloud%' OR 'users.storename' like '%cloud%' order by sales.id DESC
```

No result is showing up. What could be wrong in query.

e.g one `user['fullname']` is CloudBuck Abc

```
if(isset($_GET["q"]) && $_GET["q"]!="")
{
    $q = trim($_GET["q"]);
    $where = "WHERE users.fullname like '%".$q."%' OR users.storename like '%".$q."%'";
}

$query = "SELECT * 
FROM sales 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId ".$where." order by sales.id DESC";
```

Comment: your $q value is `CloudBuck Abc` and like query will not work if there is no such string. In the query example you are using `cloud`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single qoutes around the column names:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId 
WHERE users.fullname like '%Cloud%' OR users.storename like '%cloud%' order by sales.id DESC
```

Because mysql will use it as string if the single quote is set.

Comment: if i do not set single quote, it starts giving error users.fullname unknown column

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Have you a table `users` with a column `fullname`?

Comment: i tried running ur copy paste and it works , however look at my edited code, what is wrong in it.?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar If you get the error "users.fullname unknown column", it is likely you don't have the column `fullname` in the `users` table.

Comment: @Sithu Yes i have, personally i think there may have been some illegal character. i Removed my code and rewrite again. Now working. Weird tho

Answer (score 1):

You are quoting the field names and this is not allowed, either use backticks if its a reserved word or do not use it.

```
SELECT * FROM sales 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId 
WHERE `users`.`fullname` like '%Cloud%' 
OR `users`.`storename` like '%cloud%' 
order by sales.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId
 WHERE (users.fullname like '%Cloud%' OR users.storename like '%cloud%') 
 order by sales.id DESC
```

Comment: Parenthesis is optional in this case.